# CodeIgniter - Call to a member function model() on a non-object

Tags: codeigniter, php

I have a login form that is being created in the view. Then in my controller I'm trying to load my model but it doesn't seem to load. Looked up a few answer here on stackoverflow and almost everybody says autoload model, import the database library,etc. I did that but I'm still getting the error

```
    Fatal error: Call to a member function model() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\\project\application\controllers\login.php on line 11 

    A PHP Error was encountered

    Severity: Notice

    Message: Undefined property: Login::$load

    Filename: controllers/login.php

    Line Number: 11
```

**login_view**

```
<?php
    $loginEmail = array('placeholder' => "Email", 'name' => "loginEmail");
    $loginPassword = array('placeholder' => "Wachtwoord", 'name' => "loginPassword");
    $loginSubmit = array('name' => "loginSubmit", 'class' => "btn", 'value' => "Inloggen");
    $loginForgot = array('name' => "loginForgot", 'class' => "link", 'value' => "Wachtwoord vergeten?");

    echo form_open('login/login', array('class' => 'grid-100 formc'));
    echo form_input($loginEmail);
    echo form_password($loginPassword);
    echo form_submit($loginSubmit);
    echo form_submit($loginForgot);
?>
```

**login_controller**

```
<?php

Class Login extends CI_Controller{
    function index(){
        $data['content'] = 'login_view';
        $this->load->view('templates/template', $data);
    }


    function login(){
        $this->load->model('login_model');
        $query = $this->login_model->validate();

        if($query){
            $data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('loginEmail'),
                'loggedin' => true

            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
             redirect('profile/myprofile');
        }
    }

}

?>
```

**login_model**

```
<?php

Class Login_model extends CI_Model{

    function validate(){
        $this->db->where('email', $this->input->post('loginEmail'));
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('loginPassword')));

        $query = $this->db->get('tbl_users');

        if($query->num_rows == 1){
            return true;
        }
    }

}

?>
```

**autoload.php**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't have a constructor, in your login controller:

```
public function __construct() {        
    parent::__construct();
}
```

Comment: I am getting the same error message while loading the model. I have tried adding the above mentioned code but its still the same. Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

According to CodeIgniter docs

> If you intend to use a constructor in any of your Controllers, you MUST place the following line of code in it:
>   parent::__construct();

Refer [CI Constructor](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#constructors) for more.